# Should the corner joints on a tiled shower bench be caulked?

Tags: bathroom, shower, caulk, seal

My shower/tub area was completely tiled, including a bench area in the back. The house-flipper did not seal the grout in any way. I’ve heard you typically caulk where the tub and tile grout meet, but what about this bench area

Should I seal with 511 the entire bench and then caulk at the seam? What about the vertical portion?

[image].

Comment: Do you know how or whether they used a wet membrane? If they used kerdi correctly, for example, no caulking is necessary. If they didn't use a membrane then no caulking might ever suffice.

Comment: Matthew D, if you do decide to caulk, use a _tiny_ bead. Trim the end of the tube minimally and at an angle to create a natural tool. Press firmly.

Answer (score 2):

I caulk all corners in the tile. This is a place where grout often cracks and caulking has some elasticity so it helps alleviate that.

So yes- vertical, horizontal, bench, tile to tub or shower pan, basically every corner. I have not used silicone for years for this. Silicone looks good for awhile but then seems to get mold or mildew forming under it and usually looks pretty bad in a few years. I use the caulking sold by the grout manufacturer that matches the grout color in either sanded or un-sanded depending on which grout was used.

Comment: I'd agree on the "caulk the corners" part, but not so much on the product recommendation. When I redid my tub surround 25+ years ago, I used whatever was the cheapest caulk (I was cheap back then). I don't remember if it was an acrylic, latex, silicone, "tub & tile" or what, but I didn't have any more or less issue with mold/mildew on the caulking than anywhere else in the bathroom. And whatever it was that I used lasted just fine until last summer when I pulled it for a refresh. Of course, a color-matched caulk would probably look better...

Comment: [Silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon#/media/File:SiliconCroda.jpg) | [Silicone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicone#/media/File:Caulking.jpg)

Comment: haha- thanks- right you are ! gotta laugh at myself sometimes...